# Do multi-channel opto-triacs with common pins exist?

Tags: components, triac, opto-isolator, packages

I am designing a circuit with many (4-128) copies of the same component. It's a 4-pin opto-isolator with opto-triac output. I am aware that the pin spacing and package width can't be much less in order to maintain isolation. However, outside the IC I am tying all of the cathodes (or anodes) together, and tying all of one side of the AC together as well. It would save me a lot of IC footprint if I could find dual or quad versions of this device with those legs already joined and brought out as a single common pin. Does such a device exist?

[image: dual channel opto triac in 6-pin package]

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, optoisolators with triac outputs are not usually manufactured in the configuration you speak of.

If board space is a concern, you can select the 4-pin triac-output optoisolators instead of the 6-pin versions which would probably allow you to pack more optoisolators on the same board space.

Toshiba does manufacture dual and quad triac-output optoisolators, [TLP525G-2 and TLP525G-4](http://www.toshiba.com/taec/components2/Datasheet_Sync/210/4367.pdf) respectively. The TLP525G-2 is a DIP-8, and the TLP525G-4 is a DIP-16. However, the individual channels within the package do not share any pins. Despite this, you might still be able to save board space by using a TLP525G-2 instead of two DIP-4 or DIP-6 optoisolators.

The dual channel version is available on [Mouser](http://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Toshiba/TLP525G-2F/?qs=%2fha2pyFaduhoQwv8BJzi%2fa6wmThge9YdVXNE9RjgDdSAPcIAr2LCaA%3d%3d) and [Digikey](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/TLP525G-2%28F%29/TLP525G-2F-ND/871316), I couldn't find a distributor that has the quad version in stock.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'm using a Mini-Flat-4 package for now, so the multi channel DIPs don't quite save space. I'll consider whether having fewer individual ICs to deal with while soldering is worth the difference (there might be 128 channels on a single board).

Comment: I think that's probably about as good as you can get, save for clever placement and PCB trace routing. Are you soldering these by hand? You may consider using [a reflow technique](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/diy-smt-reflow-toaster-oven-skillet-or). :-)

Comment: I haven't yet mastered two-sided reflow, so I'll have to do at least half of them by hand.