# How to solder surface mount chip

Tags: soldering, packages

I have to solder a chip in a TSSOP-20 package on a board but unfortunately I have no "pcb oven". During the design I had access to a such oven but it's no longer possible. After some search on internet, I found many post about DIY pcb oven. As far as I understood, the heat is monitored to fit the soldering curve on the datasheet. 
[image]

I don't have time to make this kind of oven or spare money to buy one. So, I wonder if it's possible to solder the TSSOP-20 chip thanks to an "unmonitored" oven?

Note that I'm jus a hobbyist, I do not need a very high quality weld.

Comment: You do NOT "weld" a tssop.  You solder them.  And, yes, they can be hand soldered with a soldering iron and fine solder.  I do it all the time.

Comment: @JRE I'm not fluent in English, so I may not use the correct therm. Yes, it's possible to do it manually, but is it possible to do it with my kitchen oven? As well as other component of course.

Comment: I wouldn't do it in an oven in any case.  And certainly not in one intended to make food in afterwards.

Comment: @JRE Not in my actual kitchen oven but in a oven not made for pcb soldering (found in the trash for instance). You wouldn't do it because it won't work or because you are skillfull enough to solder the chip by hand?

Comment: I'm just an amateur and I can drag solder TSSOP-20 fine. It would be a good chance to develop the technique, just make sure to use plenty of flux.

Comment: @RogerRowland I have flux at home, so it will be fine. I will practice on a unused board before solder the part. This skill might (will) be useful latter anyway. How do you process? You first place some flux on the board and then place the chip?

Comment: I first put a small blob of solder on diagonally opposite pads, then tack the chip down on those two with a fine tip. Then I use a flux pen to flood a row of pins and drag solder with a chisel or hoof tip. Repeat on the other side and clean up any bridges with a little drag away from the affected pins.

Comment: Place the chip and solder two opposite corner leads. Then apply plenty of flux and drag solder each row of leads. I use a special mini-hoof cartridge with my Metcal system.

Comment: @RogerRowland The flux I use is in syringe but it will works the same way. Thanks a lot !

Comment: @M.Ferru: Use solder wick if your pins get shorted while soldering. Even consider using lots of flux. That'll make your joints solder cleanly.

Comment: I solder pin by pin using fine solder, and clean up bridges (if any) with solder wick.  I not inclined to use an oven at all.  You need solder paste (that goes bad.). You need a solder mask (has to be made for each project.). You need an (expensive) temperature controlled oven.  Then, you put down solder, place all your parts (hoping they stick to the paste and you don't know any others out of place,) place in oven (careful not to sneeze or wiggle the board,) heat (hope you got the temperature profile correct,) check for bad connections and fix them by hand.  Or just hand solder and be done.

Comment: My hands are shaking like hell all the time and still TSSOP-20 is a piece of cake. I use 0.4mm conical tip and 0.25mm solder and some flux. Trust me, if I can do this, you certainly can do this too. Just a little bit of practice and you'll be fine.

Comment: Hobbiest or not, you need a good quality solder job.

Comment: I use tape across half the chip to hold the part in place on the board, can be really sloppy with the solder, almost no skill required.  then use a wick to clean up, be careful not to drag that perpendicular to the pins you can bend them, just dont move the wick while touching.  take the tape off do the other side.  very little skill required.  easier than surface mount leds and resistors and such, which are not that hard...

Comment: @RogerRowland Can you rewrite your comment "I first put a small blob..." as an complet answer so what I can accept it?

Comment: I'm actually in hospital recovering from surgery right now, feel free to use parts of my comment as your own answer.

Comment: @RogerRowland I answered my own question. I hope you the best for your surgery

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I finally soldered the chip on my own without a reflow oven. It was way easier than I was expecting, thanks to many comments and some videos found on YouTube.

Materials:

- Soldering iron, 2mm head
- Solder wire with incorporated flux
- Flux in a syringe

I first tinned the top-left pin footprint in order to be able to place the chip for further solder. I then melted the tin again and placed the chip with a little clamp with accuracy to make sure that all the pins were on the corresponding pin footprint. I then soldered the opposite pin. After that, I was sure that the chip would not move during the rest of the process.

I started to solder each pin one by one until two pins got linked due to my lack of soldering skill. To correct my mistake, I put a drop of flux on and then I heated both pins with the soldering iron. With much surprise, it appears that it perfectly corrected the mistake. For the other side, I linked half the pins together on purpose and then use some flux. It's way easier, faster, and produced a cleaner soldering result.

Here is the result of the process:

[image]

---

I did some research about the oven part of the post. It appears that it's possible to use an unmonitored heat control oven (like a kitchen oven) to solder an entire board at once. Since it's non-monitored, it is not advisable to solder sensitive chips. However, it's pretty safe to solder every resistor and capacitor with the oven and then solder chips like this with a soldering iron. (Now I know how to do it properly so it's no big deal.)

But please, **DO NOT use the oven you are using to bake food!**

Solder wire/paste releases toxic fumes when it melts, so use a dedicated oven that you are sure to not use again.

---

I made this answer with the help of comments left by other users.

This post might seem useless for experienced people but I think it can help other people like me who have no real experience in soldering.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to use a temperature profile, and the chips you solder (not weld) to the board don't have to work either. If you don't follow the temperature profile, your not guaranteed that the chip will work. I've seen some chips fail.

Skillets work in a pinch, so do toaster ovens, but these don't follow a profile and have uneven heating. There are two bad things that can happen:

1) The uneven heating causes parts to be misaligned (which is easily fixable if a soldering iron is accessible)

2) You get too much heat, and burn up parts, some chips are some sensitive then others, for example: mems parts are extremely sensitive to thermal stress or humidity. It may be worth it to invest in a cheap oven if working with expensive parts or if time is valuable to you.

That being said, almost all chips are solderable as a hobbyist with only a soldering iron. As long as the pins are on the outside of the chip an iron can melt the solder and get the job done. The main idea is you have enough flux to help the solder to only stick to the metal and run a blob of solder past the pins, it will only stick to the pins.

QFN's with pins underneath are solderable especially when the pads are extended beyond the part. Even exposed pads (the kind used for thermal sinking) that are underneath TSOPS or DFN's are solderable if you create a via for heating underneath the chip.

If you want to remove chips, however a heat gun may be required (or you could just clip it off if your careful and solder on a new one)

BGA's and LGA's need a hot air gun minimum.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible. I have soldered 7x7mm QFN-48 package successfully using only heatgun. I did this by pre-soldering the pins on pcb with iron. Then place the chip. And last carefully descent the tip of the gun towards target. When the solder flows the chip  should find it's place. Just take your time as the soldering curve shows.

You can also use solderpaste but be careful about the amount of paste.

Check before that your heat gun is hot enough.

Comment: I'd just use the iron for a QFN.  As long as it doesn't have a bottom pad, it'll hand solder no problem.

Answer (score -2):

I've never soldered surface mount devices, but I know that I can because of YouTube.  I could type lots regarding how it's done, but I suggest that the best advice you'll get is to YouTube "Soldering SMD".  There are lots of videos.

There are also videos of people who have used simple skillets on cooker tops to solder SMD.  It doesn't seem to damage the PCB, so if something this crude works, a basic oven would probably work.  Just keep an eye on it and stop when all the paste has flowed.  The important thing is that it's just one chip, so unless your oven is extremely uneven, visual temperature control should be possible.

Comment: I solder the chip by hand finally. I watch lot of video about soldering electronic board with reflow oven. This is why my question came in. And there is still not answer to it

Comment: @M.Ferru If you found a particular comment to be so helpful that you would accept it as an answer - perhaps Roger Rowland's comment on drag soldering, perhaps a different one - you can ask them to write it as an answer.

Comment: Yes I'm thinking about it but none of each comment really answer the question either. I'll wait a bit to see if some answer shows up. If not, I'll ask someone to rewrite a comment as an answer and then accept it as you suggest

Comment: @M.Ferru Have you sought an answer in the list of _Related_ questions that appear alongside yours?  You might find some joy there.

Comment: No I didn't, otherwise I won't ask that question

Comment: @M.Ferru Even https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/diy-smt-reflow-toaster-oven-skillet-or/1187#1187 which uses a standard oven and has 17 up votes and is the accepted answer?  Perhaps I've misunderstood the question :-(

Comment: @M.Ferru You can write your own answer if you want to: self-answered questions are entirely acceptable. Good photos (in focus, well-lit, and well-framed) and some comments on what worked and what went wrong would go a long way to being appreciated by others.